# xmlstarlet select and update xml

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing, xmlstarlet

I'm trying to select the value of an xml file that matches a particular element(with specific value). For example the xml file below:

```
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>group1</groupId>
                    <artifactId>art1</artifactId>
                    <version>0.0.1</version>
                    <groupId>group2</groupId>
                    <artifactId>art2</artifactId>
                    <version>0.0.2</version>
                    <groupId>group3</groupId>
                    <artifactId>art3</artifactId>
                    <version>0.0.3</version>
                    <groupId>group4</groupId>
                    <artifactId>art4</artifactId>
                    <version>0.0.4</version>                        
            </dependency>
```

I'm trying to use this command but it gives a blank response.

> xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//groupId[@artifactId="art1"]/version' -n test.xml

if I try to use just this command, it gives me the list of group id's

> xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//groupId' -n test.xml

```
group1
group2
group3
group4
```

I just need to get the version number of a particular group Id and then I will update it so something like, if groupid = group1 and version = 0.0.1 then i will update the version to 0.0.1-done using xmlstarlet..

Any help will be appreciated as I'm new to using xmlstarlet. I tried reading some documentations but I'm really lost..

Comment: Did my answer help or are you still having issues?

Comment: @DanielHaley this works perfectly. Thank you very much. (I just need to add the namespace something like that on my original xml) but nonetheless I works great.

For the update I forgot to mention that I want to rewrite the original file, found that I need to add --inplace but still I will not be able to figure it put without you. Thank you very much :)

Comment: You’re very welcome! Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`artifactId` isn't an attribute so `@artifactId` won't select anything.

If you want the value of `version` when `artifactId` = "art1", it would look like this...

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//artifactId[.='art1']/following-sibling::version[1]" test.xml
```

If you're really wanting to do this:

> if groupid = group1 and version = 0.0.1 then i will update the version
>   to 0.0.1-done

You should use the [`ed` command](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html#idm47077139594320) instead...

```
xmlstarlet ed -u "//groupId[.='group1' and following-sibling::version[1] = '0.0.1']/following-sibling::version[1]" -x "concat(.,'-done')" test.xml
```

output...

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>group1</groupId>
  <artifactId>art1</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-done</version>
  <groupId>group2</groupId>
  <artifactId>art2</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.2</version>
  <groupId>group3</groupId>
  <artifactId>art3</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.3</version>
  <groupId>group4</groupId>
  <artifactId>art4</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```